# Server stops reading Client messages unexpectedly

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, client

As an exercise on multithreading and server/client communication, I'm simulating operations on a bank account.

The code below works until there's enough money in the bank for the request a client is making. Then, for example, if there's $7 in the bank and a client (class Teller) is asking for $10 the Server responds with a string: "Thread # could not get this amount of money", as it's supposed to be. The problem is after this message is printed out, my Server class will not respond to subsequent requests of any kind: either higher or lower than the amount of money the bank owns.

```
public class BankServer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BankServer bankServer=new BankServer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public BankServer() throws IOException{
    account=new BankAccount();
    ss=new ServerSocket(PORT);
    while(!account.isEmpty()){
        Socket client=ss.accept();
        new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(client,account)).start();
        numberOfThreads++;
    }
}

private int numberOfThreads=0;
private BankAccount account;
private final static int PORT=8189;
private ServerSocket ss;}
```

The BankAccount class in which the money are stored is built up like this:

```
public class BankAccount {
public BankAccount(){
    amount=100;
}

public boolean getMoney(int qnt){
    lock.lock();
    if(qnt>amount){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" could not get this amount of money: $"+qnt+".");
        return false; //the bank doesn't have enough money to satisfy the request
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" got his money: $"+qnt+".");
    amount-=qnt;
    lock.unlock();
    return true;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    lock.lock();
    System.out.println("Money in the bank: "+amount+".");
    if(amount<=0){
        lock.unlock();
        return true;
    }
    lock.unlock();
    return false;
}

private int amount;
private ReentrantLock lock=new ReentrantLock();}
```

Ant this is the ConnectionHandler, a class I'm using to manage every single connection from users to the bank.

Comment: Don't know what is `lock`, but you aren't unlocking it in the first `if` of the `getMoney` method

Comment: Thanks. The dumbest error I could possibly make. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is `lock`, but you aren't unlocking it in the first `if` of the `getMoney` method

```
public boolean getMoney(int qnt){
    lock.lock();
    if(qnt>amount){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" could not get this amount of money: $"+qnt+".");

        //unlock here?

        return false; //the bank doesn't have enough money to satisfy the request
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" got his money: $"+qnt+".");
    amount-=qnt;
    lock.unlock();
    return true;
}
```